# How to do the Error Handling with Python Sockets?

Tags: python, sockets

I am not sure what is going wrong with the below code. I am trying to make the socket connection and want to handle all errors using the try-except but getting error. In this case its failing on TimeoutError.

Error:

```
<ipython-input-101-07e71cdc89b9> in get_certificate(hostname, port)
     24         sock.close()
     25         return HostInfo(cert=crypto_cert, peername=peername, hostname=hostname)
---> 26     except socket.error as error:
     27         return
     28 

AttributeError: type object 'socket' has no attribute 'error'
```

Code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import idna
import socket
from socket import socket
from collections import namedtuple

def get_certificate(hostname, port):
    hostname_idna = idna.encode(hostname)
    sock = socket()
    try:
        sock.connect((hostname, port))
        peername = sock.getpeername()
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD) # most compatible
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = SSL.VERIFY_NONE

        sock_ssl = SSL.Connection(ctx, sock)
        sock_ssl.set_connect_state()
        sock_ssl.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname_idna)
        sock_ssl.do_handshake()
        cert = sock_ssl.get_peer_certificate()
        crypto_cert = cert.to_cryptography()
        sock_ssl.close()
        sock.close()
        return HostInfo(cert=crypto_cert, peername=peername, hostname=hostname)
    except socket.error as error:
        return
import concurrent.futures
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as e:
        for hostinfo in e.map(lambda x: get_certificate(x[0], x[1]), HOSTS):
            if hostinfo == None:
                print("Data Not Available")
                continue
            else:
                print_basic_info(hostinfo)
```

Comment: You imported the name `socket` twice. Once the module and once the function in the module.

Comment: @KlausD.Even after fixing the import thing, SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET') not caught with exception handling.